# Cambiar forma de imagen matplotlib

Tags: python, python-3.x, imagen, numpy, matplotlib

como podría cambiar la forma de un una matriz ?, descargue un archivo en formto .mat y cuando lo leo y traigo las imágenes, que están en matrices me da la siguiente forma:

```
import h5py
file = h5py.File('file.mat','r')
imgs = file["images"]
print(imgs.shape)
(2284, 3, 640, 480)
```

Si yo quiero plotearlos no podría porque plt.imshow() tendría que recibir  matrices de la forma (2284,640,480,3), intente con reshape dándole la forma que quiero, pero al plotearlo me sale una imagen que no es correcta:

```
x = imgs[0].reshape(640,480,3)
plt.imshow(x) #ploteo
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Probe lo siguiente :

```
img = imgs[0] # tomo la primera imagen 3x640x480
aux = list()
for i in range(img.shape[0]): #recorre 3 veces
   aux.append(img[i])
x = np.dstack(a) # junto las 3 matrices
plt.imshow(x) #ploteo
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Hay alguna forma de hacerlo mas simple o una funcion??

Answer (score 1):

Lo que puedes hacer es mover el axis de los canales **`c`** a la posición final de forma que matplotlib pueda ver las imágenes normalmente.

Pasar de (n, c, w, h) a una matriz (n, w, h, c), mueves el axis **1** a la posición final **-1**

```
    imgs = np.moveaxis(imgs, 1, -1)
```